# error in my overloaded function cursor PLS-00103

Tags: oracle

CREATE TABLE mm_student
(sid NUMBER(8,0) CONSTRAINT PK_mm_student_sid PRIMARY KEY
                 CONSTRAINT NN_mm_student_sid NOT NULL,
sname VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT 'UNKNOWN'
                 CONSTRAINT NL_mm_student_sname NULL,
gender CHAR(1)  CONSTRAINT CK_mm_student_gender_MFN
                CHECK(gender IN ('M','F','N'))
                CONSTRAINT NN_mm_student_gender NOT NULL,
edate DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
                CONSTRAINT NN_mm_student_edate NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE mm_course
(cid CHAR(8)    CONSTRAINT PK_mm_course_cid PRIMARY KEY
                CONSTRAINT NN_mm_course_cid NOT NULL,
cname VARCHAR2(50) 
                CONSTRAINT NL_mm_course_cname NULL,
location VARCHAR2(50)
                CONSTRAINT NL_mm_course_location NULL,
ccost NUMBER(6,2) DEFAULT 575.00
                CONSTRAINT NL_mm_course_ccost NULL);

CREATE TABLE mm_grade
(sid NUMBER(8,0) 
                CONSTRAINT NN_mm_grade_sid NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT FK_mm_grade_sid FOREIGN KEY(sid)REFERENCES mm_student(sid),
cid CHAR(8)
                CONSTRAINT NN_mm_grade_cid NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT FK_mm_grade_cid FOREIGN KEY(cid) REFERENCES mm_course(cid),
mark NUMBER(5,2) 
                CONSTRAINT CK_mm_grade_range
                CHECK(mark BETWEEN 0 and 100)
                CONSTRAINT NN_mm_grade_mark NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_mm_grade PRIMARY KEY (sid, cid));

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_Show_Course_Name_And_Mark
    (P_SID NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    AS
        V_CNAME VARCHAR2(50);
        V_MARK NUMBER(5,2);
        V_OUTPUT VARCHAR2(1500);
    CURSOR C_CNAMES IS SELECT C.CNAME, G.MARK
        FROM mm_course C, mm_grade G 
        WHERE G.SID = P_SID AND
        G.CID = C.CID;
    BEGIN
        OPEN C_CNAMES;
        FETCH C_CNAMES INTO V_CNAME, V_MARK;
        IF C_CNAMES %NOTFOUND THEN
            V_OUTPUT := 'The Student' ||TO.CHAR(P_SID)||'did not take any courses';
        ELSE 
            WHILE C_CNAMES %FOUND LOOP
            V_OUTPUT := V_OUTPUT || V_CNAME||'##'||TO.CHAR(V_MARK)||'##';
        FETCH C_CNAMES INTO V_CNAME, V_MARK;
    END LOOP;
    END IF;
    CLOSE C_CNAMES;
    RETURN V_OUTPUT;
    END FN_Show_Course_Name_And_Mark;
    /
    SHOW ERRORS;
```

LINE/COL ERROR

---

16/37    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TO" when expecting one of the following:
         ( - + case mod new null 
          
         continue avg count current max min prior sql stddev sum
         variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval date
         
           pipe

Answer (score 1):

Function name is `TO_CHAR`, not `TO.CHAR`

Comment: For one function, a typo, yes. Twice? Probably a typo as well. The whole discussion should / will be deleted.